# From 1 module call macros from 2 separate modules

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have 3 separate modules embedded in the same active workbook (i.e. not in personal.xlsb).

From the module named **Run_DelCols_Del_NoComms**, I want to call in consecutive order the macros from these 2 modules:

- DTJJKAYdelCols
- DTJJKAYDelNoComms

When run separately on active workbook, both code sets execute without error.

**'*************REVISED CODE USING SYNTAX “Module_Name.Procedure_Name”*****
'*************Note: in this case "Module_name"="Procedure Name"***********_**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Run_DelCols_Del_NoComms()

    Call DTJJKAYdelCols
    Call DTJJKAYDelNoComms

End Sub

Compile error:
Expected variable or procedure, not module.
```

I'm stumped because I've seen the "CALL" function work in other SE posts with identical syntax (except, of course, for different module names).

Note: The names of the "called" subs were copied/pasted into the calling module. So I don't think that's the error.

Please teach me what's producing the compile error. Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures "The Call statement is not required, but if you use it, you must enclose any arguments in parentheses." so if you just want to call DTJJKAYdelCols, your code is `DTJJKAYdelCols`. If you want to `Call` DTJJKAYdelCols, your code is `Call DTJJKAYdelCols()`

Comment: I read Alex's suggested article but couldn't run code with parenthesis. However, his suggestion prompted me to search/find this: (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures.) "If you want to call the VBA Sub procedure that is located in a different module, you need to clarify this by:

    Stating the name of the relevant module before the name of the procedure.

    **Using a dot (.) to separate module name & procedure name."

syntax “Module_Name.Procedure_Name”.** Edited OP code above executes now without error.

Comment: @WyoWindStorm,, to call the Macro no need to enclose with bracket or quotes even, it should `Call Macro Name`, **the prime reason behind the error is,, expected if the module containing `sub Macro Name` the Subroutine but not the Function** . Better share the Macro, possibly is naming conflict.